# Objective-C Memory management: ViewController in a ViewController that's inside a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with three ViewControllers (A, B, and C). In ViewControllerB I have a UIScrollView. The UIScrollView consists of several instances of my PhotoViewController. These PhotoViewController objects are called from ViewControllerA, not ViewController B, where they're located.

The PhotoViewController instances have a UIImage and a two buttons. And at first, when I clicked on a button in one of my PhotoViewController instances I received a 'Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"' error. Looking around on stackoverflow that error seems to appear whenever there are memory management issues.

Since I was creating the PhotoViewController objects in a loop from a method called in ViewControllerA, and releasing those objects, I figured that by the time I switched over to ViewControllerB they were already released - and hence the memory issue.

But that's just my guess. Could you tell me if I should just stop releasing the PhotoViewController objects inside of the loop code? Because that's what I did (just commented that line out) and the program "works" fine. However, I'm still not sure if this is the proper way to handle it and if it is causing unknown memory management issues.

Here is some of my code:

ViewControllerA.m

//Creating an album in ViewControllerB, the photos in the album are PhotoViewController objects

```
-(IBAction)showAlbum:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //Go goes here to get an album and display it in the UIScrollView
    albumID = @"ALBUM_ID";
    NSString* graphUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos?limit=10", albumID];
    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphUrl andDelegate:self];    
}

...

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    //Code for array of photos
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    NSString *requestType = [request.url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/" withString:@""];

    if ([requestType isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos?limit=10", albumID]]){
        NSArray *photoAlbumArray=(NSArray*)[result valueForKey:@"data"];
        [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [photoAlbumArray count]]];
        for(UIViewController *controller in self.tabBarController.viewControllers)
        {
            if([controller isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerB class]])
            {
                ViewControllerB *mtbvc = (ViewControllerB *)controller;
                [mtbvc setArray:photoAlbumArray];
                self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;//switch over to the second view to see if it worked
            }
        }
    }
...
@end
```

ViewControllerB.m

//loop where I create PhotoViewController objects

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    arrayCount = [array count];
    scroller.delegate=self;
    scroller.pagingEnabled=YES;
    scroller.directionalLockEnabled=YES;
    scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;

    //should have an array of photo objects and the number of objects, correct?
    scrollWidth = 0;
    scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(arrayCount*scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount;i++) {
        PhotoViewController *pvc = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil];        
        UIImageView *scrollImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(scroller.bounds, scrollWidth, 0)];
        CGRect rect = scrollImageView.frame;
        pvc.view.frame  = rect;
        [pvc view];
        pvc.label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        id individualPhoto = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",individualPhoto);
        NSArray *keys=[individualPhoto allKeys];
        NSLog(@"%@",keys);
        NSString *imageURL=[individualPhoto objectForKey:@"source"];
        //here you can use this imageURL to get image-data and display it in imageView  
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
        NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        pvc.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        pvc.label.text = [individualPhoto objectForKey:@"id"];
        //check to make sure the proper URL was passed
        //I have an imageView next to the UIScrollView to test whether that works - it does.
        [scroller addSubview:pvc.view];
        [scrollImageView release];

        //[pvc release];

        scrollWidth += scroller.frame.size.width;
    }


    if (arrayCount > 3) {
        pageControl.numberOfPages=3;
    } else {
    pageControl.numberOfPages=arrayCount;
    }
    pageControl.currentPage=0;
    //[self.view addSubview:scroller];
}
```

PhotoViewController.m

```
#import "PhotoViewController.h"


@implementation PhotoViewController
@synthesize label, imageView;

-(IBAction)likeButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //code goes here 
    for(UIViewController *controller in self.tabBarController.viewControllers)
    {
        if([controller isKindOfClass:[DemoAppViewController class]])
        {
            DemoAppViewController *davc = (DemoAppViewController *)controller;
            [davc likePicture:self.label.text];
        }
    }
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;//switch over to the third view to see if it worked
}

-(IBAction)skipButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //code goes here
}

-(IBAction)likeCommentButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //code goes here
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

PhotoViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DemoAppViewController.h"
#import "MyTabBarViewController.h"

@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    UIButton *likeButton;
    UIButton *skipButton;
    UIButton *likeCommentButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;

-(IBAction)likeButton:(UIButton *)sender;
-(IBAction)skipButton:(UIButton *)sender;
-(IBAction)likeCommentButton:(UIButton *)sender;


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

To write iOS apps, it is critical that you understand the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i).

In ViewControllerB, viewDidLoad, you alloc the pvc.
Further down, you add the pvc's view as a subview of the scroller.  This retains the pvc's view, but not the pvc itself.  Then when you release the pvc, it's retain count is zero, and when you reference it later, it's gone. Crash.  It seems like you need to pass in and retain a reference to the pvc in the controller that's using it.

Comment: Thanks @Rayfleck - I understood everything up until the last sentence. When you say I should pass in and retain a reference to the pvc do you mean just "setting" a pvc in the ViewControllerB? ... like `[svc setViewController:pvc]`??? And would I need to pass in and retain a reference for each pvc object?

Comment: Yes.  In svc declare @property (nonatomic,retain) PhotoViewController thePvc;    Then  you can just say   svc.thePvc = pvc;  That will retain it.  "for each pvc object" - yes for each instance of a pvc.

Comment: Hi @Rayfleck - i tried doing that just now and it didn't work. And I think the problem stems from svc (ViewControllerB) being the controller in which the loop occurs (i.e., where I alloc init the pvc). So essentially I'm doing self.thePVC = pvc in ViewControllerB. Can you help me figure out where I'm going wrong? Because I'm still having trouble visualizing where to apply your suggestion.

Comment: Not sure if my last comment helped, but basically ViewControllerB is the controller that's using pvc. Your initial repsonse mentioned that I "need to pass in and retain a reference to the pvc in the controller that's using it". Since ViewControllerB is where I alloc the pvc, where should I retain a reference to it?

Comment: Let's back up a minute - what exactly does the log say when the app crashes - what line is it on?

Comment: IF I do [pvc release] at the end of the loop in ViewControllerB it crashes. The line I see when it stops is `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);` and it says `Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. If I don't do [pvc release] it runs without any stops.

Comment: I added NSLog to the button in PhotoViewController that causes the crash. The error messages starts off with: `2011-07-11 16:22:17.897 DemoApp[5579:207] -[__NSCFType likeButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c2b070
2011-07-11 16:22:17.947 DemoApp[5579:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType likeButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c2b070'
*** Call stack at first throw:`

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the buttons?  How do you relate the button to the pvc?

Comment: PhotoViewController is done in interface builder. I updated my code with the header file. The implementation file isn't very different from that above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using `PhotoViewController`(Subclassing `UIViewController`) instead of `PhotoView`(subclassing `UIView`). As you are not using any of the facility of the viewcontroller(no life cycle method and other).

If you subclass `PhotoViewController` with `UIView` and remove the viewcontroller's methods it will work and will not cause any memory issues as you have aleready discussed in your discussion with *Rayfleck*. ( it will be retained by parent view controller.)

If you are thinking about the events, then these will also be handled by view itself. But if you want to handle it in your controller then you can easily delegate, or pass your controller reference and invoke the event on it.

Thanks,

Comment: thanks Ravin. I tried doing that but the UIViews never showed up. Also, it kind of messes up other sections. Thanks though :-)